# What Are 2 Opposite Meaning Words Put Together Called?

Tags: meaning, antonyms

For example if you said,'a beautiful tragedy', the words 'beautiful' and 'tragedy', are completely different things.
What is the English concept of putting these two words together to describe something?

Comment: This is a good explanation for [oxymoron](http://www.literarydevices.com/oxymoron/)

Answer (score 2):

Google defines ***oxymoron*** as "a figure of speech in which apparently contradictory terms appear in conjunction".

A canonical example is "jumbo shrimp".

Comment: A *true* canonical example is 'government intelligence.'